# Best way of sending a file to SQL server and save it, then reading it from DB?

Tags: sql-server, vb6, file, append

I am developing a software with vb6.0 :( .
I wanna to know that what the best code for saving a file in SQL server  and  then reading from it is?

I should say that I use ADODB.Stream when saving file.....

what is you suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to save to sql. An alternative, and IMO better solution is to save the docs to a folder on your regular file system and save the reference to it in sql.
Unless you have specific reason for wanting to save in sql?

Is there a specific reason you need to use vb6. Legacy?

Here is an example in .NET on achieving what you require, it should be pretty straightforward to convert to VB6

http://www.jstawski.com/archive/2007/05/17/save-documents-with-sql-server-and-display-them.aspx

UPDATE: With VB6 an example using ADODB.Stream to store and retrieve images, which should be similar to what you need:

http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/14246

Comment: Thanks, Yeah, I have to complete an old system which has beed developed by vb6.0. Any suggestion in vb6.0?

Comment: What about the suggestion of saving files to your regular file system? Is that not an option?